# Selenium Grid Steps for Bamboo to mulitple EC2 instances

Tags: c#, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-grid, bamboo

**TOOLS**: C#.NET/Selenium/Nunit, Bamboo, AWS, Selenium Grid

I have separate AWS EC2 instances.
1 for Bamboo
1 for our Application
1 for our Selenium Tests

We then build in Bamboo and deply to the Application instance. I need to then initiate my Selenium Tests. The selenium tests reside on there own AWS Instance. This is where my problem lies.

How do I activate the Selenium Tests on that other EC2 from the Bamboo build task?

- The 3 individual EC2 Instances make this very difficult.
- I have tried a command task with AWS Remote Command. This works, but PowerShell forces the tests to run in a headless browser. The tests fail with random inconsistencies.

Please help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've come up with this:

1) In Bamboo create a Remote Executable: Agents - Remote Agents - Shared Remote Capabilities. Add capability. NUnit Runner. Path I believe is the NUnit-Console.exe... Please correct me if I'm wrong there.

2) Next, go to the Job. Add a NUnit Runner Task. The executable created above will show up in the Executable dropdown. Now add the path to the .dll... that would be local on the remote EC2/Agent. For our purposes we deploy the Selenium tests on that remote agent.

Not posting on two forums, more here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Step-By-Step-Instructions-setting-up-Selenium-Tests/qaq-p/707575#M17020